# Connection timeout from host MongoDB compass to docker mongo replication

Tags: replication, mongodb, docker

`docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongodb-primary:
    image: mongo:latest
    hostname: mongodb-primary
    container_name: mongodb-primary
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/primary:/data/db
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all
```

By using docker inspect I can see port binding in `NetworkSettings`:

```
"Ports": {
      "27017/tcp": [
      {
          "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
          "HostPort": "27018"
      }]
}
```

When using `docker-compose up` I issued `mongosh` command and used `rs.initiate()`. Now I can see `rs0:PRIMARY` in mongo shell. And in `rs.config()` I can see host `172.22.0.2:27017` (I changed mongo-primary host name to ip of container and issued rs.reconfig()).

Now in `mongoDB compass` in URI I entered `mongodb://localhost:27018` and I can see `Server selection timed out after 30000 ms`.

**Note that** when I start a single node mongo with no replication everything works as expected and I can login to Mongo via Compass, but in replication mode I have issues when trying to connect to my single node replication.

In `docker-compose` log I can see:

```
mongodb-primary    | {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-23T06:46:24.631+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.22.0.1:60604","uuid":"46dec71f-8a72-4e2b-9731-c8220543960f","connectionId":69,"connectionCount":4}}
mongodb-primary    | {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-23T06:46:24.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn69","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.22.0.1:60604","client":"conn69","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Compass"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"5.6.0"},"platform":"Node.js v18.12.1, LE","os":{"name":"darwin","architecture":"x64","version":"22.1.0","type":"Darwin"}}}}
mongodb-primary    | {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-23T06:46:24.649+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn69","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.22.0.1:60604","uuid":"46dec71f-8a72-4e2b-9731-c8220543960f","connectionId":69,"connectionCount":3}}
```

What is the issue and how I can resolve this issue?